# Install MSP with Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is part of the powershell script I have to install an MSI. I was just given a patch (MSP) and I am not sure how to install the patch (MSP) with this MSI? Any help would be awesome!

```
Execute-MSI -Action Install –Path 'IRDesktop.msi' -Parameters "/QN"
```

Comment: Did you try it already? What error message did you receive? If you are not in the folder where the executable is, I would put the full path there.

Comment: Also, where does this Execute-MSI come from. I have seen multiple questions referring to it lately and I have never seen it before. Without knowing what it is and what it does I would have a hard time telling you how to use it.

Comment: Looks like it comes from the App Deployment Toolkit (http://psappdeploytoolkit.com/) which has an Execute-MSP function. I would suggest starting there.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.

Execute-MSI -Action Patch -Path 'IRDesktop.Patch.6.4.41.4086.msp' -Parameters "/QN"

Comment: @mpeytonfan18 https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

`Execute-MSI` is part of the `PSAppDeplyomentKit`. The `PSAppDeploymentKit` also has the function `Execute-MSP` for MSP files.

> Reads SummaryInfo targeted product codes in MSP file and determines if the MSP file applies to any installed products
>   If a valid installed product is found, triggers the Execute-MSI function to patch the installation.

Example

```
Execute-MSP -Path 'Adobe_Reader_11.0.3_EN.msp'
```

If you want to use `Execute-MSI` explicitly, change the `Action` from `Install` to `Patch` for MSP files.

Example

```
Execute-MSI -Action 'Patch' -Path 'Adobe_Reader_11.0.3_EN.msp'
```